# RazorEngine WebApiTemplateBase @Url.Content()

Tags: asp.net-web-api, razorengine

How can I get `@Url.Content()` working in my `_Layout.cshtml` when RazorEngine is being used from ASP.NET Web API?

[RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/) (v.3.7.2) only deals with the Razor syntax and not the additional helper methods like `@Html` or `@Url`. These can be added by extending the `TemplateBase<>` and setting it in the configuration.

There are code examples in some old issues: [#26](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/26), [#29](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/29); in an unreleased, incomplete piece of code in [MvcTemplateBase.cs](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/blob/3.7.2/src/source/RazorEngine.Mvc/MvcTemplateBase.cs); and in the documentation for [Extending the Template Syntax](https://matthid.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Extending-the-template-Syntax).

My problem is I'm using ASP.NET Web API (v.1) which won't have `HttpContext.Current` (nor should it). I want to provide a `UrlHelper` as I want to use its `Content()` method but it needs to be instantiated with the `HttpRequestMessage` which won't be available.

Perhaps there's no way to get @Url helper methods for my compiled layout. Perhaps I need some other way of getting the absolute path from the virtual path. It seems I'd still need some way of checking the Request though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to get this working is to follow the direction set by [Extending the Template Syntax](https://matthid.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html#Extending-the-template-Syntax) and use `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute()` in a helper method.

```cs
using System.Web;
using RazorEngine.Templating;

namespace MyNamespace.Web
{
    public abstract class WebApiTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
    {
        protected WebApiTemplateBase()
        {
            Url = new UrlHelper();
        }

        public UrlHelper Url;
    }

    public class UrlHelper
    {
        public string Content(string content)
        {
            return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Set up the TemplateService configuration with this extension of the `TemplateBase<>`.

```cs
var config =
    new RazorEngine.Configuration.TemplateServiceConfiguration
    {
        TemplateManager = new TemplateManager(),
        BaseTemplateType = typeof(WebApiTemplateBase<>)
    };
```