# URL generation with RazorEngine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine, url.action

I'm currently using Razorengine to generate emails outside of asp.net. However I'm unable to use @url.action in my template as follows becuase the it's not part of Razor.

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")">@Url.Action("Details", "Comment", new { id = @Model.Comment.Id }, "http")</a>
```

This is how I generate the viewengine:

```
var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));
```

How can I use @url.action with razorengine?

Comment: What do you mean @Url.Action is not part of Razor?

Comment: @Ryan it's not part of the razorengine

Comment: I beg to differ. I use it all the time, it's very useful.

Comment: `Url.Action` derives from `System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper` and needs `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` for Razor implementation, make sure your view engine includes those required namespaces. Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Tesuya RazorEngine derives from `RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase<T> instead of System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<T>` You are all getting confused between RazorEngine and Razor view engine that is used by ASP MVC. See the following post: http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-part-04-taking-a-step-back-behind-the-scenes-of-razor-and-razorengine/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RazorEngine WebApiTemplateBase @Url.Content()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461041/razorengine-webapitemplatebase-url-content)